# CRM 2011 register Report on Team entity

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I made two Reports that should be registered on the Team Entity in MS CRM 2011.
Now when I create the Report inside MS CRM i can not choose the team entity.

#### Report Form

[image: Report Form]

But as far as I know you should be able to register it on Team, because in the Team Form you can run Reports.

#### screenshot

[image: See the screenshot]

How can I register Reports on Team?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an easy solution. You have to create the Report using the Report Wizard inside CRM. In the dialog that opens you can set the Primary Record Type equal to "Team". Once the Report has been created you can change the Report Type to Existing File and then upload your .rdl File.

The Report will then show up under Team.

Answer (score 0):

Although there seems no out of the box way to configure a report to show up in "Team" related reports section, you could use the SDK to append team entity into the list of entities the report is configured to show up (Related Record Types). 
"ReportEntity" entity stores the references to the list of all the related record types the report is configured to show up under.

```
        var reportEntity = new ReportEntity()
        {
            ReportId = new CrmEntityReference(Report.EntityLogicalName, reportId), //the ID of the report you want to show up in "Team" areas
            ObjectTypeCode =  "team"
        };
        organizationService.Create(reportEntity);
```

I have verified and the report does show up under "Team" although the actual report "Related Record Types" shows an empty string followed by a ";" which tells me UI is not configured to recognize team as a related record type.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I finally found a solution that doesen't requires some code.